# Having troubles inheriting base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

When I inherit the base class, it's telling me there is no such class

This is enhanced.h:

```
  class enhanced: public changeDispenser // <--------where error is occuring
    {
    public:
        void changeStatus();
        // Function: Lets the user know how much of each coin is in the machine
        enhanced(int);
        // Constructor
        // Sets the Dollar amount to what the User wants
        void changeLoad(int);
        // Function: Loads what change the user requests into the Coin Machine
        int dispenseChange(int);
        // Function: Takes the users amount of cents requests and dispenses it to the user

    private:
        int dollar;
    };
```

This is enhanced.cpp:

```
#include "enhanced.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enhanced::enhanced(int dol)
{
    dollar = dol;
}

void enhanced::changeStatus()
{
    cout << dollar << " dollars, ";
    changeDispenser::changeStatus();
}

void enhanced::changeLoad(int d)
{
    dollar = dollar + d;
    //changeDispenser::changeLoad;
}
```

This is changeDispenser.h:

```
class changeDispenser
{
public:
    void changeStatus();
    // Function: Lets the user know how much of each coin is in the machine
    changeDispenser(int, int, int, int);
    // Constructor
    // Sets the Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, and Pennies to what the User wants
    void changeLoad(int, int, int, int);
    // Function: Loads what change the user requests into the Coin Machine
    int dispenseChange(int);
    // Function: Takes the users amount of cents requests and dispenses it to the user
private:
    int quarter;
    int dime;
    int nickel;
    int penny;
};
```

I didn't include the driver file or the changeDispenser imp file, but in the driver, these are included

```
#include "changeDispenser.h"
#include "enhanced.h"
```

Comment: Did you include `changeDispenser.h` inside of `enhanced.h` before the declaration of `enhanced`?

Comment: That fixed the error, but it sparked another error in the changeDispenser.h

Error 1 error C2011: 'changeDispenser' : 'class' type redefinition

Comment: You need include guards - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to put header of the class `changeDispenser` in separate header file and include it in derived class header.

The class `changeDispenser` doesn't have default non-argument constructor, so you need to initialize it explicitly in the derived class. Something along the lines:

```
enhanced::enhanced(int dol) : changeDispenser(0, 0, 0, 0)
{
    dollar = dol;
}
```

Or you could define default values for the constructor arguments, which is less preferable for stylistic reasons.

```
changeDispenser(int i=0, int j=0, int k=0, int l=0);
```

Comment: Yes, that's a problem too - didn't notice.

Comment: I added #include "changeDispenser.h" to the top of my enhanced.h header file, and I added enhanced::enhanced(int dol) : changeDispenser(0, 0, 0, 0) in the enhanced.cpp file, but now it's saying 'changeDispenser' : 'class' type redefinition

Also, the constructor in the changeDispenser.h is defined by the user in the driver file and is passed through.

Comment: If you consider you question is answered, you can accept the answer by pressing green V.

Answer (score 1):

If the source code you posted correctly shows the three files (enhanced.h, enhanced.cpp (?), changeDispencer.h) making up this group of classes, then you should add

```
#include "changeDispenser.h"
```

to the top of "enhanced.h" to always make sure that the definition of `changeDispenser` is available when some part of your code includes the definition of `enhanced` (coming from "enhanced.h"). To subclass a class, the complete definition of the base class must always be available.